# How to directly index an array returned by the find function

Tags: arrays, matlab

```
tmp = find(A > 0); %// A is a matrix
value = tmp(1);
```

In this case, I want to get the first value of the array `find(A > 0)`. How can I use only one line instead of two?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the index of the first `true` value in condition, one uses:

```
ix = find(A>0, 1, 'first');
```

Please not that `ix` will not be necessarily a single element; if condition is not fulfilled anywhere, `ix` will be empty.

Generally, to return the first `k` indices of the `true` values in the condition, use:

```
ix = find(A>0, k, 'first');
```

or, for the last `k` indices that are true:

```
ix = find(A>0, k, 'last');
```

with the same caveat: do not expect the returned values to have `k` elements; always check the `size` or the `numel` of `ix`.

Comment: Thx a lot, I forgot to use `help find`.

Answer (score 1):

It is easy:

```
A = rand(300,1);
T = find(A>0.8,1)
T =
     4
```

`k = find(X,n)` returns the first n indices corresponding to the nonzero elements in X.

Answer (score 0):

To find the **`n`-th value** (not necessarily the first) that fulfills the condition `A>0` you can use

```
value = A(find(cumsum(A>0)==n, 1));
```

For example,

```
>> A = [1 0 5 0 4 0 2 -3];
>> n = 2;
>> value = A(find(cumsum(A>0)==n, 1))
value =
     5
```

**How it works**:

`cumsumn(A>0)` increases whenever an entry fulfills the condition `A>0`. In the above example,

```
>> A
A =
     1     0     5     0     4     0     2    -3
>> cumsum(A>0)
ans =
     1     1     2     2     3     3     4     4
```

So the index of the first time that `cumsum(A>0)` reaches `n` is the index of the entry of `A` that you want.

Comment: Get a new method! Wonderful!